# How to get accountexpirationdate real date?

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the actual date of accounts that have expired but still enabled in the active directory. I always get the date + 1 day. For example, if a user is expired today (15/11/2022), it will shows (16/11/2022)... Can you help me with this?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter *  -properties AccountExpirationDate |
Where-Object{$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt (Get-Date) -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -ne $null -and $_.Enabled -eq $True} |
select-object Name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate |  Sort-Object -Property {$_.AccountExpirationDate} -Descending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to include LDAP property `accountExpires` in there (PowerShell conveniently converts this to local time in Property `AccountExpirationDate`)
to first check if the attribute has never been set (value 0) or if the attribute for the user has been set to 'Never Expires' (value 9223372036854775807).

Try

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).Date  # set to midnight

# or use -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -Properties AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires |
Where-Object {($_.accountExpires -gt 0 -and $_.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807) -and 
              ($_.AccountExpirationDate -le $refDate)} |
Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate | 
Sort-Object AccountExpirationDate -Descending
```

Comment: Ive tried but it still displays the wrong date... i need the "end of" date... ive tried to .addhour(-24) but still not working...  any idea if theres something to do with

[datetime]::tryparseexact([cultureinfo]("en-CA"), [globalization.datetimestyles]("None"),[ref]$refDate  ?

Comment: @ak2595 So basically you want the date where at the end of that day the account expires, which would typically be the AccountExpirationDate. In that case just use `.AddDays(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Theo, ive found what i was looking for

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -Properties AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires |
Where-Object {($_.accountExpires -gt 0 -and $_.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807) -and 
              ($_.AccountExpirationDate -le $refDate)} |
Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, @{Name="AccountExpirationDate";Expression={(get-date $_.AccountExpirationDate).AddDays(-1)}} | 
Sort-Object AccountExpirationDate -Descending
```

Comment: You don't need the get-date there, it is already a datetime object